# Ubuntu 6 display with GTX 1070 * 2

Tags: ubuntu, multi-monitor, graphics

Does any one know how to set up multi monitor with multi GTX?

I try to set up 6 displays with dual GTX 1070 under OS:Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04.

this is my PC config:

- DELL workstation Precision T7500
- CPU : Xeon 5690 * 2
- memory : RDMM 16Gb * 12
- GPU : ASUS TURBO GTX 1070 * 2
- Display : Philips 246E(1920*1080) * 4 and Philips 323E(1920*1080) * 2

I want set up 6 monitor with double GTX 1070.(like following)

```
+--------------------++--------------------+

|    323E(1) GPU1    ||  323E(2) GPU1   |

+--------------------++--------------------++--------------------++--------------------+

|    246E(1) GPU2    ||    246E(2) GPU2    ||     246E(3) GPU2   ||     246E(1) GPU2  |

+--------------------++--------------------++--------------------++--------------------+
```

But dual 323E aren't reflected.(Ubuntu recognizes dual 323E and 1070, but DeskTop vie(etc) aren't reflected well.Only mouse cousor is recognized).

It would be greatly appreciated if you could explain the details.

And I installed nvidia-driver-440.
Followings are nvidia-smi imformations.

Wed Aug  5 01:32:00 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |

|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |

| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|======================+======================+======================|

|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A | 
| 24%   52C    P8     8W / 151W |      2MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 00000000:04:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 24%   55C    P0    31W / 151W |    347MiB /  8114MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|====================================================================|
|    1      1091      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            78MiB |
|    1      1693      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           137MiB |
|    1      1897      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         119MiB |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

(I'm Japanese, and apologize for my poor English. )

Answer (score 0):

Did you already install the binaries provided by nvidia? Proprietary drivers work best for nvidia cards. After installing those you have the nvidia-config command which should provide you with all the tools necesarry.

Comment: Thank you for your advice ! From nvidia-smi info, I might installed nvidia 440-100 driver.